# perl, how do I use an array without assigning it to a variable first?

Tags: arrays, perl, dynamic

Here's what I currently do in my program

```
@array = split /\n/, $longstring;
$data = $array[14];
```

I really only want to get the element at position 14 out of the array and use that, the other stuff in the string is not useful to me. I know that in a language like java I could do something like this

```
$data = (split /\n/, $longstring)[14];
```

which is what I want to do but in perl.

So how do I access array elements without having to assign the array to a variable first?

edit: hmm, ok what about this

the long way

```
my $data = "abc\nd^e^f\nghi";
my @a = split (/\^/, (split /\n/, $data)[1]);
print $a[2];
__OUTPUT__
f
```

the short way

```
my $data = "abc\nd^e^f\nghi";
my $a = split (/\^/, (split /\n/, $data)[1])[2]; # line 60
print $a;
__OUTPUT__
syntax error at script.pl line 60, near ")["
Execution of script.pl aborted due to compilation errors.
```

this confuses me more than usual since it works on the inner split, but not the outer split

edit 2:

I'm a little confused as to why these two lines are different

```
my $a = (split  /\^/, (split /\n/, $data)[1])[2]; # works
my $a =  split (/\^/, (split /\n/, $data)[1])[2]; # doesnt
```

here's my thought process for the 2nd line which is what I wrote originally (in other words, this is what I think my program is doing)

```
my $data = "abc\nd^e^f\nghi";
my $a =  split (/\^/, (split /\n/, $data)[1])[2];
my $a =  split (/\^/, ("abc", "d^e^f", "ghi")[1])[2];
my $a =  split (/\^/, "d^e^f")[2];
my $a =  ("d", "e", "f")[2];
my $a =  "f";
```

That's what I expect to happen, can someone point out where my thinking has gone awry?

Comment: What are you really trying to do?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'm just going to explain why these lines are different:

```
my $r = (split  /\^/, (split /\n/, $data)[1])[2]; # works
my $r =  split (/\^/, (split /\n/, $data)[1])[2]; # syntax error
my $r = (split (/\^/, (split /\n/, $data)[1]))[2]; # but this works
```

In Perl, you can use an array subscript like `[2]` on a list in parentheses (it's called a [list slice](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldata.html#Slices)).  But there's another rule that says "If it looks like a function call, it's a function call."  That is, when you have the name of a function (like `split`) followed by optional whitespace and an open parenthesis, it's a function call.  You can't subscript a function call; you'd need to add an extra set of parentheses around it.  That's why my third line works.

On another note, you should never say `my $a` or `my $b`.  `$a` and `$b` are special package variables that are used with `sort`, and if you've turned them into lexicals, you'll have weird problems.  Even if you're not using `sort` at the moment, you might add it later.  It's easiest to just completely avoid ever making `$a` or `$b` lexical.

For readability, I might adjust the whitespace a bit and add a comment:

```
my $r = (split /\^/, (split /\n/, $data)[1] )[2]; # get 3rd field of 2nd line
```

Answer (score 4):

You've just misplaced the first `(`, try this:

```
my $a = (split/\^/, (split /\n/, $data)[1])[2];
```

Comment: This may work, but IMHO it's far less readable and less obvious what you are trying to do. Assigning to variables with meaningful names would make this code a lot better.

Comment: @Graeme Perrow : I completly agree with you, but this answers the question of the OP who had a syntax error with his code.

Comment: @bourbaki - Yes, I suppose I should have made my comment on the question, not your answer. But it does answer the question, so +1.

Comment: The single line can easily be expanded into 3/4 lines but I didn't like the idea of having 2 arrays which are only used in back to back lines. That's just my opinion, do you advise I do this for readability though?

Comment: @Rob - Readability should be paramount, at least until you have a **verified** performance issue.  Ugly code is miserable for the person who has to modify it down the road, and that person will usually be you.

Answer (score 1):

What you've written is fine.

[Here's a demo at codepad](http://codepad.org/nFrTCpLM).